# How should I see the skype chat history from the file main.db located at ~/.Skype/SKYPEUSERNAME/?

Tags: 12.04, skype, sqlite

I'm using **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS** and **Skype 4.3** on my machine. I've taken a file named **main.db** from the location on my machine ~/.Skype/SKYPEUSERNAME/

Now I want to see the chat history from that file with each of the contact. For it I installed **Sqliteman** but I'm still not able to see the chatr history. Can someone please provide me the easiest though effective solution for this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want the absolutely easiest way to see your history, check out [www.skypebrowser.com](http://www.skypebrowser.com/). It does exactly that.

Answer (score 6):

Messages are stored as XML in `messages` table. You may use a simple SQL command to extract need dialog:

```
sqlite3 .Skype/yourusername/main.db "select timestamp,body_xml from messages where dialog_partner=\"partnerusername\";"
```

As you may use Sqliteman to run same command:

```
select timestamp,body_xml from messages where dialog_partner="partnerusername";
```

Comment: instead of `timestamp` use `datetime(timestamp, 'unixepoch') as date`, otherwise +1 as it fixes the bug in the skype client which shows empty history for all contacts

Comment: Also I'd include the `author` field to get a log with proper sender per message

Comment: What about chat groups? How can you correctly indentify them?

Comment: At least on my main.db, the table is Messages (with a capital), not messages  (all lower case). I use:  
sqlite3 -csv main.db "select datetime(timestamp,'unixepoch'),dialog_partner,body_xml from Messages where dialog_partner != \"\";" > Skype_messages.csv

Comment: Putting many of the above comments together with my own ideas, I'd use `sqlite3 main.db "select datetime(timestamp, 'unixepoch') as date,author,body_xml from messages where dialog_partner=\"partnerusername\";" >  out.txt`. This saves the output in a useful txt file that shows the author's names and gives the date/time in a human-readable format.