# How to find Skype main.db in Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, skype

i want search on my skype history is used following link to do so [How should I see the skype chat history from the file main.db located at ~/.Skype/SKYPEUSERNAME/?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527583/how-should-i-see-the-skype-chat-history-from-the-file-main-db-located-at-skyp)

**i have the following configuration**

- Ubuntu  16.04 LTS
- Skype 5.0.1.1

Comment: Please could you better explain as I don't what `i have used following configration Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Skype 5.0.1.1` means in this situation!

Comment: @George I don't no about other things, can you give me idea on that, what other informaltion you need to solve issue.

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind but still i could  not found any db file of Skype. not even .Skype directory.

Comment: If there is no main.db does that not also imply your chat history is not stored on your machine?  Knowing Microsoft they'd like to store that info on their servers.

Comment: @Rinzwind you may be right! but those things are not working as per this site saying 
http://www.skypebrowser.com/

Comment: The `~/.Skype` folder is for the old version of the Skype client, isn't it?

Comment: @gunner may be you are right. So how can I do make search on chat history. There should be some in file ? Do you have any idea about this

Comment: Thanks  all of you. New version 8.30.0.50 of Skype have a search function over all chat

Answer (score 7):

You will find everything inside `/home/{user_name}/.config/skypeforlinux/` directory on Ubuntu 16.04. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I found it in

```
home/snap/skype/common/.config/skypeforlinux/skylib/live#{skypeusername}
```

inside this you will see **main.db**

my system is **ubuntu 18.04** and **skype** version is **8.34**, Hope it will help someone

** please make sure hidden files are visible otherwise you will not see .config folder

Answer (score 0):

Config folders are usually hidden in ubuntu, The skype folder is hidden. You need to enable showing them.

Open nautilus (File Manager), press `ctrl+h`, you will be able to see hidden files/folders. Go to the folder with the name .Skype.

**main.db** in the below path should have what you are looking for:

```
.Skype/<;skype_account_id>
```

ex: `.Skype/chudasamachirag`

You can view this file in a sqlite application, such as [SQLiteStudio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt).
(Select Database> Add a database, and give the path of this main.db file)

Comment: Did you check this with skype 5 and ubuntu 16.04 or higher? And in case you wonder why I ask: see comments.