# lost contact list on skype

Tags: 18.04, skype

I've just upgraded to the LTS 18.04, I've installed Skype, logged in with my personal account and discovered that my entire contact list is gone...

Does somebody know whether/how I can recover it?

Comment: `mv ~/.config/skypeforlinux ~/.config/skypeforlinux.old` and restart.

Comment: I think on 18.04 it puts Skype in a Snap Folder now in the home folder. I don't have Skype but the programs I use this is the case.

Comment: @EODCraftStaff yes, I confirm that skype is in the Snap Folder

Comment: @kenn that command line is not working: there is no .config file neither in /home nor in /home/snap

Comment: I use `flatpak` for running Skype, you can install it from source. It may take sometime but you ll have an alternative against Snap https://askubuntu.com/questions/906472/how-do-i-install-vlc-3-0-on-ubuntu-zesty-17-04/987076#987076

Comment: I found the .config file in the snap/skype/common directory

Comment: ok the old config should be in /home/{name}/.config/skype, copy and paste it to the new snap folder. Sry, I was in Windows earlier...work. ctrl + v show hidden directories.

Comment: @EODCraftStaff no, there is no old config there...

Comment: You said that you upgraded to 18.04, so it's not a clean system, maybe it's conflicting with old settings, so purging old Skype a reinstalling it may fix it.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't use Skype Sry...I'm not sure where the old config would be.

Comment: If you do Purge it will be gone for good. Where would the old config file be @kenn?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/936900/how-to-find-skype-main-db-in-ubuntu Its a database file ending in .db.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 16.04, it's in `~/.config/skypeforlinux`

Comment: Maybe it's a useful information: I did not upgrade form 16.04, i installed 18.04 from scratch. And I thought that the contact list could be recovered after installation just by logging in for the first time (at least it was the case in the past)

Comment: As far as I know Skype retrieves contacts list, but not sure about chat history. I don't want to mislead you. I am not sure!

Comment: Try this link Web Skype https://web.skype.com/

Comment: I just tried this, it does all what Skype does except  sharing desktop: https://github.com/stanfieldr/ghetto-skype